# MongoDB database disappeared after Kill

Tags: javascript, linux, mongodb, mongoose

I have a database running just for referral collection and tracking and wasn't thinking much about it when I restarted my EC2 instance. I haven't ever had problems restarting with Mongo before so when I logged in I naturally didn't think anything could be wrong. However, after starting up the mongo daemon with `sudo mongod --dbpath ./db` I saw **all the collections were gone**. I did a check using `show dbs` and saw that, indeed, the populated database from moments ago had disappeared and I was left with the three standard empty DBs.

**Is there any way to recover my data?** Perhaps it has been moved to a temp folder or such. I scoured the net for some answers, and I'm positive I haven't been hacked (this whole situation happened in the span of 5 minutes) and I'm also positive I didn't drop the database. All services were running fine when I restarted the EC2 instance (scaling it up). Don't see any related warnings when starting up Mongo earlier. The only weird thing I can think of is that I had a duplicate index issue earlier today caused by a document having two null fields, that I fixed right away, and then tested to ensure there was no further issue.

Comment: There always exists the way to recover data - it's when you use a backup.

Comment: Also, make sure that you start Mongo server on localhost, and do not expose it to Internet. There is a lot of hackers sitting and waiting for your widely open Mongo port.